# Where was the Scottish Skyfall scene filmed?

Tags: james-bond, skyfall, film-location

I know Scotland very well and have several theories of my own but can anyone tell me where this iconic shot was taken?

Ideally I'm after as accurate a location as possible as I'm fairly sure I can narrow it to one of two valleys (bonus points for a streetview link!)

[image: Skyfall Shot]

Comment: The Skyfall House was actually a mock up and filmed on Hankley Common in Surrey - nowhere near Scotland!

Comment: They use a shot of scottish mountains in the build up to the scenes at the house. But the house, grounds, drive and gate were built in Surrey. Bourne Wood to be specific. A popular location for film makers, it has hosted many huge films such as Thor: Dark World, Gladiator, Sherlock Holmes, Skyfall (to name a few!). Incredible place, if you're lucky enough to live nearby you are able to just wander up to many of the film sets.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually I think it's here:

[Skyfall in Glen Etive](http://tinyurl.com/pa3c8mk)

The little bridge in front of Bond is the land mark.

Comment: I'm going to swap the accepted answer to this one because I believe you're closer - good work :-)

Comment: Good catch, Rob! You are spot on.

Comment: I know the area pretty well having climbed all the hills in the Glen Coe area. I wonder if the mist was added digitally or they were just lucky. Then again, Scottish hills often look like that ;-)

Comment: When I was preparing for the trip through Scotland, a colleague of mine kept talking about the mist. I asked, "O.K., mist... but what about the rain there?". He said: "No, you don't understand. Scottish mist **is** rain." :-)

Answer (score 14):

The shot was taken in Glen Etive, Highland, Scotland. The water to the left is the River Etive. I believe this link is the exact spot, but not entirely sure.

[Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Glen+Etive,+Highland,+Scotland,+UK&hl=en&ll=56.616414,-4.946117&spn=0.001318,0.003012&sll=38.776731,-77.176719&sspn=0.118971,0.192776&hnear=River+Etive&t=h&z=19&layer=c&cbll=56.616518,-4.946239&panoid=_STxqf26bxbybfc_GbomNQ&cbp=12,286.18,,0,8.98)

Comment: That was pretty much exactly where I was thinking too but I wasn't sure!  Funny, I was down there last week getting bitten by clegs - didn't see a blown up house ;-)

Comment: HAHA! Yup ... I'm thinking the site of the "Skyfall" house is probably not in that area ;-)

Comment: I did actually see some pictures of them building out of wood so given the darkness of the scene it could be anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the exact location you will find here [location with streetview](https://www.google.com/maps/@56.6194936,-4.9313981,3a,75y,267.65h,65.13t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sPjrTLrfNaaDNl1CCWbfNAw!2e0?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this could be the exact spot, it overlooks the farm that my great great grandfather was born and family lived on.

https://www.google.com.au/maps/@56.619486,-4.931301,3a,75y,264.51h,87.73t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sxkhirGtn7FM5HPEGHu_Qvw!2e0

You can see the little bridge that the road crosses is just to Bonds right in the movie shot. It is beside the River Etive in Glen Etive in the Highlands. You can see the same bends in the river and the valley looks the same etc.

Comment: Have you checked the existing answers?