# Was there a real Skyfall house in Scotland?

Tags: james-bond, skyfall, film-location

I was re-watching Skyfall, and saw that his parents' house was supposed to have been in Scotland. I was guessing right next to Hogwarts.

So, the question is, is Skyfall house a real lodge/house in Scotland, or was it made up for the movie?

Comment: Related http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/12883/where-was-the-scottish-skyfall-scene-filmed

Answer (score 4):

OK, decided to look into the BlueRay extras and found it.

According to Blue Ray Extra #14: "The Beginning of the End", the house was not actually in Scotland. It was designed and filmed in [Hankley Common](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankley_Common), in Surrey, England. Screenshots from ~3:15 min into the Extra:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Was this house actually existing? Because some comments on [this related question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/12883/49) say it was explicitly built for the movie out of wood. But this fact isn't entirely clear from the answer (though, I guess the *"designed"* could be interpreted this way?).

Comment: The common in question is just a common. A local described it to me as a bowl-shaped area with no man-made landmarks visible from horizon to horizon, which makes it an attractive film set. So no, the house didn't exist. The other reason to film it there is that Bond has historically been filmed at Shepperton Studios, SW London, which is a short drive away. If it had been a real house, it wouldn't be there any more: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=skyfall+house+explosion

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - I read it as they built it from scratch, but it was not 100% clear